# Java: clone or copy random generated numbers into sort methods and count number of comparisons and swaps

Tags: java, sorting, random

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;


public class Sorting
{
   public static int numOfComps = 0,  // Number of comparisons
                     numOfSwaps = 0;  // Number of swaps

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      System.out.println("\n\nSelection Sort:");
      System.out.println("\n\nQuick Sort:");

      System.out.println("\nOriginal order:\n");
      int size = 5;

      ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(size);

      for(int i = 1; i <= size; i++)
      {
         list.add(i);
      }

      Random rand = new Random();
      while(list.size() > 0)
      {
         int index = rand.nextInt(list.size());
         System.out.print(list.remove(index) + " ");
      }
      //Sort the array
      selectionSort(list);
      quickSort(list);

      System.out.println("\nSorted order: ");
      System.out.print(list + " ");
   }

   public static void selectionSort(int[] array)
   {
      int startScan;   // Starting position of the scan
      int index;       // To hold a subscript value
      int minIndex;    // Element with smallest value in the scan
      int minValue;    // The smallest value found in the scan

      // The outer loop iterates once for each element in the
      // array. The startScan variable marks the position where
      // the scan should begin.
      for (startScan = 0; startScan < (array.length-1); startScan++)
      {
         // Assume the first element in the scannable area
         // is the smallest value.
         minIndex = startScan;
         minValue = array[startScan];

         // Scan the array, starting at the 2nd element in
         // the scannable area. We are looking for the smallest
         // value in the scannable area. 
         for(index = startScan + 1; index < array.length; index++)
         {
            if (array[index] < minValue)
            {
               minValue = array[index];
               minIndex = index;

               numOfSwaps ++;
            }
            numOfComps ++;    //get 15 comparisons here
         }

         // Swap the element with the smallest value 
         // with the first element in the scannable area.
         array[minIndex] = array[startScan];
         array[startScan] = minValue;

         //numOfComps ++;    // Get 5 comparisons here
      }
       System.out.println("\n\nNumber of comps = " + numOfComps);
       System.out.println("Number of swaps = " + numOfSwaps);
    }

    public static void quickSort(int array[])
    {
      doQuickSort(array, 0, array.length - 1);
      System.out.println("\n\nNumber of comps = " + numOfComps);
       System.out.println("Number of swaps = " + numOfSwaps);
    }

    /**
      The doQuickSort method uses the QuickSort algorithm
      to sort an int array.
      @param array The array to sort.
      @param start The starting subscript of the list to sort
      @param end The ending subscript of the list to sort
    */

    private static void doQuickSort(int array[], int start, int end)
    {
       int pivotPoint;

       if (start < end)
       {
          numOfComps++;

          // Get the pivot point.
          pivotPoint = partition(array, start, end);

          // Sort the first sub list.
          doQuickSort(array, start, pivotPoint - 1);

          // Sort the second sub list.
          doQuickSort(array, pivotPoint + 1, end);
       }
    }

    /**
      The partiton method selects a pivot value in an array
      and arranges the array into two sub lists. All the
      values less than the pivot will be stored in the left
      sub list and all the values greater than or equal to
      the pivot will be stored in the right sub list.
      @param array The array to partition.
      @param start The starting subscript of the area to partition.
      @param end The ending subscript of the area to partition.
      @return The subscript of the pivot value.
    */

    private static int partition(int array[], int start, int end)
    {
      int pivotValue;    // To hold the pivot value
      int endOfLeftList; // Last element in the left sub list.
      int mid;           // To hold the mid-point subscript

      // Find the subscript of the middle element.
      // This will be our pivot value.
      mid = (start + end) / 2;

      // Swap the middle element with the first element.
      // This moves the pivot value to the start of 
      // the list.
      swap(array, start, mid);

      // Save the pivot value for comparisons.
      pivotValue = array[start];

      // For now, the end of the left sub list is
      // the first element.
      endOfLeftList = start;

      // Scan the entire list and move any values that
      // are less than the pivot value to the left
      // sub list.
      for (int scan = start + 1; scan <= end; scan++)
      {

         if (array[scan] < pivotValue)
         {
            endOfLeftList++;
            swap(array, endOfLeftList, scan);

                //numOfSwaps ++;
         }
         numOfComps++;
       }

      // Move the pivot value to end of the
      // left sub list.
      swap(array, start, endOfLeftList);

      // Return the subscript of the pivot value.
      return endOfLeftList;
    }

    /**
      The swap method swaps the contents of two elements
      in an int array.
      @param The array containing the two elements.
      @param a The subscript of the first element.
      @param b The subscript of the second element.
    */

    private static void swap(int[] array, int a, int b)
    {
      int temp;

      temp = array[a];
      array[a] = array[b];
      array[b] = temp;
      numOfSwaps++;
    }
}
```

How do I clone or copy the random generated numbers to the Selection Sort and Quicksort methods so that both sort methods have the same random generated numbers? And did I correctly place the number of comparisons and number of swaps codes into each sort method? Also, I'm trying to set up the output so that each sort method under the sorter name (i.e. Selection Sort) shows the original order of random generated numbers, the number of comparisons, the number of swaps, and the sorted order of numbers. How do I code that output? One more thing, when I run the code, I get a compile error stating that the required argument is "int[]" for the sort method but found "ArrayList". How do I fix this? I have thoroughly searched on Google for these answers to no avail. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Create a second list based on the first:

```
  ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(size);
  // fill list
  ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>(list); // pass the first list in
```

Then pass each list to the respective sort method, and print each one out:

```
  //Sort the LIST
  selectionSort(list);
  quickSort(list2);

  System.out.println("\nSorted order: ");
  System.out.print(list + " ");
  System.out.print(list2 + " ");
```

You might want to pick better names than `list` and `list2`. If both lists are sorted correctly, you'll be better able to tell if you have the correct number of comparisons and swaps.

---

Addressing some of your added questions:

1. you can count swaps by creating a field `int numSwaps`, setting it to 0 each time you begin the sort, and incrementing it `numSwaps++` each time a swap occurs. Same goes for comparisons.
2. you can print arrays by writing `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(yourArray));`
3. to get rid of that compile error, turn your ArrayList into an array before passing it in: `quickSort(list.toArray(new Integer[list.size()]));`

Comment: I added 2 more questions.

Comment: Edited, hope that helps. If new concerns come up, you should generally try to apply any new info you learned, and then ask a new specific question, after accepting the answer that best answers this current question. Seeing that you accept answers in your previous questions encourages people to answer future questions that come up.

Comment: Will follow your advice. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Did you notice if I placed the comparisons and swaps codes correctly in each sort method?

Comment: The compile error I'm getting now is: required: int []; found: Integer[]

Comment: @Jeremy try looking that up, and if you can't find anything, post a new question with just the 2-4 lines of code that produce that error :)

Comment: Will do. I appreciate your help.